# Response returns a 302 instead of a 401 http status

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm building a REST api using express and I want to add authetication to the app. On the client side I have a Angularjs application.

I have this code for the authentication request

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
```

But this code returns a 302 http status, which isn't very helpful in a REST api application. I guess a 401 status code would be more helpful.

I have installed `passport-google 0.3`

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: A 401 status code would not be correct. The user **is** authorized to access /auth/google, because it's where you go to perform authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that `passport-google` has been intended to be used from REST API.

`302` is a redirect status code. `passport-google` expects that `/auth/google` page has been opened in a browser, so it's redirecting user to google.com authentication dialog.

Try opening it in your browser and what will happen.

### Update:

I have a feeling that you picked up the wrong tool. Look at [`passport-localapikey` module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport-localapikey), or search for any other REST authentication solution.

I don't think that you'll be able to use `passport-google` from pure REST API without hacking it (e.g. monkey-patching its internal parts).

Comment: I know that it has to be opened. There's a request header value named Location and the value is the user google authentication dialog. But when the response status code is 302 I'm not able to read this value. It has to be a 401 status.

Comment: @user49126 How do you expect your authentication flow to work?

Comment: @user49126 why not just call `window.open('/auth/google')` from your client-side application?